# position item in a center

Tags: html, css, slider

I have a very simple question, yet I cannot figure out how to solve it.

I have a slider, where in the middle I want to display some text like below:
[image]

The problem is, that I cannot force it to align middle vertically with the image. Here is my CSS:

```
.caption {
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    zoom: 1;
    color: white;
    display:table;
    left:20%;
    width: 60%;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    padding: 10px 0;
    background:rgba(138, 138, 138, 0.55);    
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: vertically at which position you want?

Comment: I would like to see the box with the text in the middle of picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already use `position` tag which is perfectly fine just use `top` property and `transform` property like this

```
.caption {
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    zoom: 1;
    color: white;
    display:table;
    left:20%;
    top:50%;
    transform:translate(0,-50%);
    width: 60%;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    padding: 10px 0;
    background:rgba(138, 138, 138, 0.55);    
}
```

> With both properties div will be vertically center no matter whatever is the height

example : https://jsfiddle.net/y2z94ez3/